# Command line net start of a service is returning "System error 5 has occurred." on Windows server 2012

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-server-2012

I ran into this error and could not find a single solution online.
My problem is that when I try and start or stop a service on a Windows 2012 Server using the command line:

> net start [service name]

It would return:

> "System error 5 has occurred. Access is denied."

Didn't matter that the user had permissions to start/stop the service (Using the GUI) it could not do so from the command line.  Kind of critical for some scripts we run.  Didn't matter that the user was an admin, didn't matter that the user has full permission in the registry.

Comment: Most likely the Services admin tool (the GUI) was running with elevated privileges (it may have elevated itself silently) and the command line window wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

Finally stumbled across the solution using Microsoft's tool "SubInAcl.exe"

Download it from their website, then run the command:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\subinacl.exe  /service \[server name][service name] /grant=[domain]\user name]=F

That gives that particular user Full permission over that service.  Soon as I did that, command line stopping/starting of a service worked perfectly for that user.